# ¿por que mi código no es capaz de darme el valor mayor y el valor menor en mi arreglo de javascript?

Tags: javascript

estoy tratando de resolver un ejercicio de JavaScript el cual debe recibir un arreglo con unas notas y me debe dar el promedio de las notas y también mostrarme cual nota es la mas alta y la nota mas baja mas sin embargo cuando quiero que me de la nota mas alta y mas baja no me retorna nada o solo me retorna la nota mayor, que debería hacer en este caso?

```
let notas = prompt('Ingrese cantidad de notas:');

let nota = [];

function estudiante(notas2) {
    let suma = 0;
    let promedio = 0;
    let notaMayor = 0;
    let notaMenor = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < notas2; i++) {
    let valor = parseFloat(prompt("Ingresa tu nota:"));
    nota[i] = valor;
    console.log (valor);
    suma = suma + valor;
    promedio = suma / notas2;

    if (nota[i] >= notaMayor) {
        notaMayor = nota[i];
        console.log('la nota mayor es ' + notaMayor);
    } else if (nota[i] <= notaMenor) {
        notaMenor = nota[i];
        console.log('la nota menor es ' + notaMenor + ' por lo tanto se convertira en 5.0');
    }
}
console.log ('el promedio es de: ' +promedio);
return nota;}}
```

let result = (estudiante(notas));

Answer (score 2):

Primero, tu función no recibe un arreglo de notas pero estás pidiendo ingresar una en cada iteración, por lo que no cumples con el enunciado. Luego, también estás imprimiendo en cada iteración, lo cual tampoco cumple tu enunciado.

Lo que debes hacer es comparar todas las notas y al final dar los resultados, quedaría así:

```js
let notas = [10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20];

function estudiante(notas) {
    let suma = 0;
    let promedio = 0;
    let notaMayor = 0;
    let notaMenor = 0;

    if (notas.length == 0){
        console.log("No hay notas");
        return;
    } else if (notas.length == 1) {
        suma = notas[0];
        promedio = notas[0];
        notaMayor = notas[0];
        notaMenor = notas[0];
    } else {
        //asumimos que la mayor y menor son la primera
        notaMayor = notas[0];
        notaMenor = notas[0];
        //comenzamos a recorrer desde la segunda
        for (let i = 1; i < notas.length; i++) {
            suma += notas[i];

            if (notas[i] > notaMayor) {
                notaMayor = notas[i];
            } else if (notas[i] < notaMenor) {
                notaMenor = notas[i];
            }
        }
        promedio = Math.round(suma/notas.length * 100) / 100; //redondeamos a 2 decimales
    }

    console.log('La nota mayor es ' + notaMayor);
    console.log('La nota menor es ' + notaMenor);
    console.log('El promedio es de: ' + promedio);
}

estudiante(notas);
```

Lo primero que debes hacer es entender el requerimiento antes de programar cualquier cosa, te lo digo por experiencia, esto te ayudará un montón a futuro.

La otra opción y tal vez más performante es que ordenes el arreglo de notas, luego el primer y último valor serían el mayor y menor, luego puedes hacer una consulta más para sumar y sacar el promedio. Inténtalo como ejercicio luego de checar esta respuesta